# How to influence 2 angles from 2 animated object?

Tags: delphi, math, angle

Hello and thanks in advance for your help

Here is what i have:

- A 2D Plan where multiple objects are moving randomly.
- Each object has a position(x,y), and an integer direction (0 to 360).

Here is what i want to achieve:

1. When 2 objects become close (let say distance < 20 pixel ), i want to make their direction to change so they become more far.
2. When they become little bit far ( distance 40 to 60 pixel ), i want to change their direction so they become more close.
3. Between 20 and 40 they follow each other ( but this part i did it easily )
4. if distance > 60 px they just ignore each other (this part is already ok as well )

I experience some difficulties for point 1 and 2:

- To compare both angles ( it's ok in simple cases but if one object angle is 359 and the other is 2, i can't find a good way to calculate that their actual direction is close, althought 359 - 2 = 357.
- To apply a small variation to both objects so they look to influencate each other.
  Just to notice: if both object's direction are extreamly different they can ignore each other.

for instance, currently i am doing that when objects are too close ( distance < 20 ):
self is the current object and b is another object of same type.

```
self.SetDirection( self.direction - ( b.direction - self.direction ));
```

And when objects are between 20-60px

```
self.SetDirection( direction + ( b.direction - self.direction ));
```

the setdirection method (i know it's ugly, and probably wrong ):

```
function TBoid.toAngle360(angle: double): double;
begin
  if angle < 0
  then angle := 360 - ( abs(round(angle)) mod 360 )
  else if angle > 360
       then angle := round(angle) mod 360;

  result := angle;
end;
```

I would be very thankfull if anyone could help me, give some any explanation or point at my mistakes.
I could not find any suitable answer on this site or in google, and i'm weak with trigonometric calculations, angles, radians and all that...

Thanks

Comment: your signs are clearly wrong. e.g if dir <0 you want 360 + dir not minus. And your mod should be direction := (dir mod 360). For exaample if dir = -20 then (360 - (-20)) = 380 not 340 which I imagine is what you are looking for

Comment: You are right, i changed my function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More reliable approach is  to minimize using angles.

Instead of angle use velocity components `vx` and `vy` (note that `vx=v*cos(direction)`, similar for `vy` and `sin`).

To compare direction similarity, calculate dot product of direction vectors (normalized by their lengths)

```
dot = (vx1 * vx2 + vy1 * vy2) / (len1*len2)
where 
len1 = Hypot(vx1,vy1)
```

Dot product has value 1 for collinear vectors, close to 1 for close directions, is 0 for perpendicular vectors, is 1 for anticollinear vectors (note this is equivalent of calculation of angle difference cosine).

To make mutual influence, apply something like gravity or Coulomb force - object makes a force (hence acceleration) onto another object. So velocity components change.

For example, you have almost collinear vectors with components `vx, vy`. Find normal vector `N`

```
nx = -vy
ny = vx
```

and add  `N*coeff` to one velocity and `-N*coeff`  to another velocity to make them divergent or convergent (depends on the sign of `coeff`). Value of `coeff` calculate correspondingly to distance between objects.

Comment: Thanks MBo
My approach of using angles is probably not the best, but i already came to the point to be able to move all objects using their position, direction(angle) and speed. 
They bounce properly on the edge of the screen as well. 
This is why i definitely think (and need) to deal with this using angle calculation..

Comment: Reflection from vertical wall is simple: `vx : = -vx; vy remains the same`, reflection from horizontal wall: `vy : = -vy; vx remains the same`. Much simpler than angle way. If you insist on using angles - similarity is `cos(angle1)*cos(angle2)+sin(angle1)*sin(angle2)`

Comment: Ok, i am now using vector calculation to compare the direction of 2 objects that are close. let say i obtain a result close to 1, how can i translate the result to apply a value to the direction property of my object ?

Comment: Missed your question. Added some clues

Comment: Thanks @Mbo, it is being more clear now. Therefore, sorry if i'm weak in math, it's ok for me to apply a coeff to the velocity according to the normal vector, but since my object is storing a `direction` in degrees, i would like to apply the result of this calculation to the angle of direction. Can you help me one more time to understand how to achieve that?

Comment: You neen to rotate by angle arctan(coeff) to achieve similar deviation, but seems it is not very helpful information because you can choose coeff arbitrarily